# Getting timezone on android with respect to GMT

Tags: android, timezone, utc, pst

I want to get the timezone on an android device with respect to UTC. For example, if I'm in PST timezone, then I want it in this format: "-0800". Is it possible?

Comment: Please add an example

Comment: my device in PST time-zone. I get "PST" for the above. I want to represent "PST" time zone in form of/with respect to "UTC". For example, PST could be represented as "UTC-08:00". I don't know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet gives me PST timezone represented as "-0800", which is UTC representation for PST. It was just a matter of formatting. Thanks to SimpleDateFormat class.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()); String
timezoneStr = new SimpleDateFormat("Z").format(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: This solution is correct and generic, works for any time zone.